# non-master branch is not being build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

My code repo is private on bitbucket and my parent bbranch is masster-php7 instead of master.
I created a bbranch from master-php7 and did some changes. Now I want to build from this branch but still fail.

On dashboard this message print after 10 minutes

git fetch --no-tags --progress -- https://abc@bitbucket.org/def/xyz.git
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10 ERROR: Checkout failed java.lang.InterruptedException  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)   at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:395)  at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:325)    at hudson.Proc.joinWithTimeout(Proc.java:171)   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2423)   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2044)  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:569)  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:907)     at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1131)  at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1167)     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:124)  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:155)    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:69)     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:303)     at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427) ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting

> In docker logs "WARNING o.j.p.w.flow.FlowExecutionList#unregister:

Owner[asif_copy_test_convo_on_devstack_before_build/1:asif_copy_test_convo_on_devstack_before_build #1] was not in the list to begin with: []"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The UI you have included is *not* for defining which branch to build, it is a part of Job configuration.

With the GUI as above, you are telling Jenkins that your job is a Pipeline job and it needs to run a Jenkinsfile. Jenkins needs to get the Jenkinsfile from Source Control (git), so it needs to know how to get that file from there. In this GUI you define it. The Repository resides at the URL you provided, the credentials are as provided, the branch name is `*/asif_imap_ev2-...`, the path to Jenkinsfile inside the repository is "Jenkinsfile" (e.g. the file resides at repo root). Jenkins tries to checkout the Jenkinsfile according to the above instructions and fails, probably because the branch name is invalid (it contains `*/`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Jenkinsfile is on root path of branch. I have also tried as following without "*/"  "asif-imap_ev2_incoming_outgoing_actions"  as "refs/heeads/asif-imap_ev2_incoming_outgoing_actions" as "refs/heads/remotes/asif-imap_ev2_incoming_outgoing_actions" but no to avail.  I try other repos with branches works file. I dont know whats problem with this branch. I used shallow clone with depth 50 then it works but after abbout 30 minutes.

Comment: The timeout as per above is 10 minutes, so any checkout longer than that will fail. Also, try to clean the workspace on your master Jenkins, it can help.

Comment: I did .Actually my repo has a lot of open branches (around 400) and our top root repo is not master but master-php7. How to tell jenkins to reach respective branch quicly?